# Chart.js - make barchart element blink

Tags: chart.js

I'm reading docs but there seems to be no parameters to do what i need: I have a plain bar chart and I need to make some bars blink depending on threshold configuration. Is there any plugin or secret parameter to obtain this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I understand, you want to have a blinking bar.

So what you can do is create the bar and then dynamically update its background-color from 'transparent' to the original color periodically using a timer.

This will create a blinking effect.

Ok, so if you want the first bar to blink:

```
let count = 0;
setInterval(() => {
  if(count % 2 === 0) {
      myChart.data.datasets[0].backgroundColor[0] = 'transparent';
      myChart.update();
  }
  else {
    myChart.data.datasets[0].backgroundColor[0] = '#FFC857';
    myChart.update();
  }
  count++;
}, 2000);
```

I don't know if there is a better solution for it, but this is the first thing that came to my mind.

Comment: thanks a lot, it's a homemade solution I ain't thounght about...but works perfetcly!